# How to forward MITM traffic through SSH tunnel?

Tags: iptables, ssh-tunneling, socks5-proxy

Using the `arpspoof` command I have created a MITM attack on another device. I would now like to forward the traffic through an SSH tunnel (SOCKS5 Proxy). Heres an example....

```
Client 1-----MITM----->Client 2------MITM-----(Router)---SSH Tunnel---->Server A
```

**Step 1: MITM**

Client 2 uses arpspoof to trick Client 1 into thinking that Client 2 is the router. Client 2 uses arpspoof to trick the Router into thinking Client 2 is Client 1.

**Step 2: SSH Tunnel**

Client 2 sets up a SSH tunnel that connects to Server A.

**Step 3: SOCKS5 Proxy**

Client 2 sets up a SOCKS5 Proxy running on localhost (127.0.0.1) that forwards traffic to Server A.

**Step 4: My Goal**

Forward the traffic from Client 1 to Client 2 and forward that to the SOCKS5 proxy and then forward that through the SSH Tunnel Server A.

Is it possible and how do I do it?

Thanks in advanced,

Josh